# Ember Data cannot read property 'async' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember v1.8 beta 3+ with Ember Data 1.0 beta 10- you receive this error:

```
Error while processing route: index Cannot read property 'async' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'async' of undefined
    at Relationship [as _super$constructor] (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:9523:46)
    at new BelongsToRelationship (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:9736:12)
    at createRelationshipFor (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:9840:16)
    at http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:6366:41
    at http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:9307:20
    at cb (http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js:15907:13)
    at OrderedSet.forEach (http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js:15703:13)
    at Map.forEach (http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js:15911:19)
    at Function.Model.reopenClass.eachRelationship (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:9306:42)
    at Ember.Object.extend._setup (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js:6365:26)
```

Despite your models being set up correctly:

```
App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.attr(),
  foo: DS.belongsTo('foo', {async:true})
});


App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.attr()
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1111/edit

Comment: Thanks man, just came up against this!

Comment: I'm using Canary for both Ember & Ember Data and have run into this.. what's up with that?

Comment: It's just a bug for now, you'll have to use an older Ember for a day until an Ember Data fix is pushed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug with Ember/Ember-data versions.  Ember changed its Map implementation in Ember 1.8 beta 3 breaking any version of Ember Data less than 1.0 beta 10.

Here's the github issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2323

It's fixed in 1.0.0-beta.11+canary.2997e47034 or above.

Comment: Has anyone resolved this problem because it seems this problem is still there with emberjs 1.9.0-beta.1 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.10. see this jsbin that shows the problem: http://jsbin.com/tiyamedeqiho/1/edit

Comment: Yeah, you need to jump to a newer version of Ember Data (1.0.0-beta.11)  Canary has the fix and it's 1.0.0-beta.11+canary.2997e47034, the version you have in the jsbin is beta.

http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js

http://jsbin.com/tiyamedeqiho/2/edit

Comment: How does one lock down their ember-cli app to this version of ED?